# GATE Jape rule annotation consisting of two words

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval, gate

I am trying to write a JAPE rule that will catch the annotation "Job Title". However, because it consists of two words I couldn't find a way to write it after the Input: section.

Thit is what I am trying to do:

Phase: ...
Input: Job Title
...

However, if I write it like that it will read it as look for annotations Job and Title, and not Job Title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the GATE data model allows arbitrary names for annotation types and features, the JAPE language can only handle types and features whose names are (more or less) valid Java identifiers - upper- and lower case letters, numbers and underscores, and not starting with a number (technically hyphens will work in some situations too, but not all). So it's best to stick to these restrictions if at all possible.

If you can't change the upstream component to generate an annotation type without the space the you may be able to use the renaming feature of the annotation set transfer PR to fix it post hoc.